# Is Servicemix Still Supported

Tags: apache-servicemix

I want to know if is ServiceMix still supported as the release date of version 7.1.x was supposed to be on 30.09.2017 as in this [link](https://servicemix.apache.org/community/releases-schedule.html) and I could not get any updates about their progress or new expected date so please if anyone has any additional information, please share it with me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question. Ask in that product's support channels (forum/mailing list/whatever).

Comment: Please close the question as @Mat suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I communicated with Mr.Krzysztof and he told me that there'll be a release soon to the newest camel and karaf.